# smallest element order $p$ in $\mathbb Z^*_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I would like to write an efficient algorithm to find the smallest element of order $p$ in $\mathbb Z^*_{p^2}$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Therefore I calculate $a^{p-1} \pmod{p^2}$ for every element a in $\mathbb Z^*_{p^2}$ and select the minimum $a$.

However it is not efficient to try all the elements for bigger $p$. Is there better way to find smallest element of order $p$?

Thanks.

Comment: p is not element of Z*_p^2

Comment: We know that $(p+1)^p\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$, so we don't really need to test all $a \in \Bbb Z^*_{p^2}$.

Comment: Well $(p+1)^r\equiv rp+1$ mod $p^2$ so $p+1$ has order $p$ and since we have $a^p\equiv a$ mod $p$ we can show that no smaller value can work.

Comment: How can we know that p+1 is the smallest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$. Therefore it has $p-1$ elements of order $p$. On the other hand using the binomial formula we see that
$$
1+p,1+2p,1+3p,\ldots,1+(p-1)p
$$
are all of order $p$. Thus the above list contains all the elements of order $p$. The smallest one appears to be $1+p$.

Comment: Mark Bennet's comment gives the answer a bit faster actually. Here we get an opportunity to recall a few basic facts about cyclic groups, so let's just do it.